# How get system (14.04) to read/recognize a blank DVD disc?

Tags: dvd

I have (recently installed)  14.04
If I insert a blank disc in the disc drive, system lights blink.  No icon appears on my screen so I can not open the disc, write a back-up or anything else.
If disc is not blank, icon does appear and I can open, read, etc. files.
What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to AU ! Format yr disc and while you at it, burn something on it. Then you will be able to see it on yr desktop, mount it and even open it with "Gnome File Manager" aka `nautilus`. ..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried formatting it in GParted?  My disk reader does the same thing for blank disks, and GParted is the only program that will read them for me.

Comment: I installed  GParted and it did (only tried once) automatically formatted and displayed a blank disc inserted in the DVD drive.  Great!